# jira-python package in pip has gone?

Tags: python, pip, jira

I tried to install jira-python via pip.

```
pip install jira
pip install jira-python
```

jira package installed normally, but jira-python package returns error that there is no matching version.

I think there seems a problem with package in pip.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira-python page also rises 404 error.

Is there any method to install jira-python package? things like install via source code or anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have been superceded or replaced by [jira](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira)

**Install:**

```
$ pip install jira
```

**Quickstart:**

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('https://jira.atlassian.com')

issue = jira.issue('JRA-9')
print issue.fields.project.key             # 'JRA'
print issue.fields.issuetype.name          # 'New Feature'
print issue.fields.reporter.displayName    # 'Mike Cannon-Brookes [Atlassian]'
```

Comment: In fact, I have a trouble because my code imports `JIRAError` from `jira.exceptions` I found JIRAError method was in `jira.utils` and modify my code to jira.utils and fixed this error. Thanks. It seems really superceded by `jira`